# How multiple azure web jobs will share instances

Tags: azure

My azure pass subscription supports 16 instances of azure webjob. Now if I host 2 webjobs, will both the webjobs get 16 instances each or 8 instances each

Comment: 16 in total. It can be 2 for webjob 1 and 16 for the other, 8 and 8 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested, when I deploy two continuous webjobs, they both share all the 16 instances, which means each of webjobs runs on 16 instances.

For continuous webjobs - they will run on all of your instances.

For triggered webjobs- only a single instance of a run can run at a given time so when triggered the webjob will run on one of your instances (randomly).

> If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-does-my-app-run-and-scale).